# python Convert string(Mar18) to Dateformat(201803)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with values like `Mar18,Apr18,Jun18`. 
I am trying to convert to dateformat like `201803,201804,201806`.
I wrote my syntax as below:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['column'],format'%b%y')
```

this gave me column as `2018-03-01,2018-04-01,2018-06-01`.

How can i convert it to date datatype like `201803,201804,201806`

What format type should i use.

Note:If this is a duplicate question please point me to previous question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [19]: pd.to_datetime(['Mar2018'],format='%b%Y').strftime('%Y%m')
Out[19]: Index(['201803'], dtype='object')
```

PS please note, this is *not* a datetime dtype - this is a string dtype

alternatively you can convert it to [`period` dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/timeseries.html#period):

```
In [28]: df
Out[28]:
    column
0  Aug2014
1  Mar2018
2  Jan2017
3  Jun2016

In [29]: df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column'], format='%b%Y').dt.to_period('M')
In [30]: df
Out[30]:
    column     new
0  Aug2014 2014-08
1  Mar2018 2018-03
2  Jan2017 2017-01
3  Jun2016 2016-06

In [31]: df.dtypes
Out[31]:
column    object
new       object
dtype: object

In [32]: df['new'].dt.daysinmonth
Out[32]:
0    31
1    31
2    31
3    30
Name: new, dtype: int64
```